# Power BI multiple lines on the y-axis

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

### Explanation of the dataset I am using

I have a dataset containing the following values:

- Timestamp
- Value
- Tag

The **combination** of a **timestamp** and a **tag** makes a row **unique**.

This dataset could, for example, make it possible to retrieve the value of tag A-A-A at 2019-05-20 00:00:00

[image: dataset]

### Goal visualization (in Power BI)

The following image shows the visualization I would like to make in Power BI.

- X-axis = Timestamp
- Y1-axis = Value of Tag A-A-A
- Y2-axis = Value of Tag B-B-B
- Y3-axis = Value of tag C-C-C

[image: to-be situation]

### Problem

I am unable to make a graph in Power BI that shows the **Value** of **each Tag** at a certain **Timestamp**.

I am curious how I can make Power BI understand that a Value corresponds to two values (Tag + Timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by putting the `Tag` column in the Legend box as shown here:

[image: Example]

Comment: Okay that's weird I tried exactly the same thing in Power BI and it's not working. Some of the values are strings instead of integers. May that be the problem?

Comment: Yeah, you really don't want strings and numbers in the same column.

Comment: The thing is that these String values are really important. For example they define which product is being produced in a machine at a certain time. While another tag could be the amount of water in this machine. Those are two types of values: String and Integers. But they have an important relation with each other. I am curious if these can be combined somehow. Why could a String not be an X value?

Comment: Also do you know if it is possible to filter the Integer values of my 'Value' column in Power BI?

Comment: Strings should be in a different column since they don't have a numeric value you can plot on a chart. You probably need to restructure your data if you have mixed types in a column.